# Error when running mahout spark-itemsimilarity - ClassNotFoundException: scopt.OptionParser

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, mahout, mahout-recommender

https://mahout.apache.org/users/algorithms/intro-cooccurrence-spark.html

Using this reference, I was trying mahout spark-itemsimilarity but getting an error when running the following command

> mahout spark-itemsimilarity --input in-file --output out-dir

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scopt/OptionParser
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scopt.OptionParser
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 19 more
```

I referred this for installing mahout:
https://github.com/apache/mahout#building-from-source 
I followed the guide exactly.

What could be the possible reason for this error? Am I missing anything?

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't download the binary Mahout? There are a lot of options in that how-to, what is your environment, Spark setup etc. I can't imagine why you would get a JNI error, are you using GPUs? Missing Scopt is something in the MVN pom.xml not set right. Also are you getting from the master branch?

Comment: Did you build with either the `-Pviennacl` or `-Pviennacl-omp` option? Those options are the only usage of JNI currently in the `0.13.0` release and `0.13.1-SNAPSHOT`.  Could you pleas provide more information?

Comment: As well do you have `mahout-spark_2.0-0.13.1-SNAPSHOT-dependency-reduced.jar` on your classpath`?

Comment: @AndrewPalumbo is correct if you are building an app but the CLI does that for you so disregard his last comment. Again I suggest you try running from the binary release, building from source is not recommended until you have a real need, there are a lot of options and profiles being worked on now.

Comment: @pferrel No particular reason for not downloading binary mahout. I'm new to this and didn't have any idea on where to start from.
Issue was with pom.xml only. I manually added scopt_2.10-3.3.0.jar in lib directory and it started working fine.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: That will only works if you don't use a cluster. Scopt is in the "dependencies-reduced.jar" which is supposed to be on the classpath and also sent to the executors. This may be a bug in the current master branch, if you could try the binary in a clean install (without altering bin) and report if that worked--it would be much appreciated. http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/mahout/

Comment: I downloaded the binary from the above link and ran the command "mahout spark-itemsimilarity -h" I got the usage text. Its working properly.
If you think its some bug then could you guide me on how and where to report?

Comment: if you got usage text it's running so now you have to supply the correct parameters, see docs here: http://mahout.apache.org/users/algorithms/intro-cooccurrence-spark.html

Comment: Tried with proper parameters. Its working as expected.